SettingWithCopyWarning when modifying DataFrame columns in Pandas
I'm encountering a SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas when trying to modify columns of a DataFrame. I've ensured to use .loc[] for assignments and also tried using .copy() on the DataFrame as recommended, but the warning persists. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
data = pd.read_csv(gps_file)
data = data[['cts', 'GPS (Lat.) [deg]', 'GPS (Long.) [deg]', 'GPS (2D) [m/s]']]
data['time'] = ((data['cts'] - data['cts'][0]) / 1000).round(2)

I consistently receive SettingWithCopyWarning despite using .loc[] for assignments. I've also tried using .copy() on the DataFrame and slices to avoid modifying a copy inadvertently, but the warnings persist.
I'm using pandas version 2.2.2 and Python version 3.12.
Here’s a version of my try with sample data:
import pandas as pd

# Sample data to illustrate the issue
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'cts': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    'GPS (Lat.) [deg]': [32.0, 32.1, 32.2, 32.3, 32.4],
    'GPS (Long.) [deg]': [34.0, 34.1, 34.2, 34.3, 34.4],
    'GPS (2D) [m/s]': [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
})

# Create a copy to avoid potential view-related issues
new_data = data.copy()
# Select relevant columns
new_data = new_data[['cts', 'GPS (Lat.) [deg]', 'GPS (Long.) [deg]', 'GPS (2D) [m/s]']]
# Calculate a new column 'time'
new_data.loc[:, 'time'] = ((new_data['cts'] - new_data['cts'].iloc[0]) / 1000).round(2)

I load the data using the following approach:
# Set the base directory containing the folders
base_dir = './sample_data'
# Initialize a dictionary to store the data
data_dict = {}

# Iterate through each folder in the base directory
for folder in os.listdir(base_dir):
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_dir, folder)
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        # Create a dictionary entry for the current folder
        data_dict[folder] = {}
        # Load gps files
        for i in range(1, 5):
            experiment_key = f'Experiment_{i}'
            gps_file = os.path.join(folder_path, f'{i}p.csv')
            if os.path.exists(gps_file):
                gps_data = pd.read_csv(gps_file)

Worked SOLUTION:
data = data[['cts', 'GPS (Lat.) [deg]', 'GPS (Long.) [deg]', 'GPS (2D) [m/s]']]
time = ((data.loc[:,['cts']] - data.loc[0,['cts']]) / 1000).round(2)
data.loc[:,['time']] = time


Please provide a [mre] that reproduces this specific issue, we can't work with pd.read_csv(gps_file).

@gtomer I have tried using the .loc[] method as recommended in that thread. Despite this, the SettingWithCopyWarning still occurs. My question seeks further clarification or additional techniques that may not have been covered in the previous answers.

Your updated example runs without SettingWithCopyWarning (pandas 2.2.2)

@mozway
data['time'] = ((data['cts'] - data['cts'][0]) / 1000).round(2)    -->
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Sorry but your question is not reproducible, and most likely your issue is coming from something that you're not clearly showing or that is already covered in the duplicate or the many existing questions on the topic.

@mozway I've found a solution and have updated my post with the details. Thanks

The below sample code works without warning:
import pandas as pd

nums = {'cts': [1, 2, 5, 6,7,8], 'void': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
data = pd.DataFrame(nums)
data = data[['cts']]
data['time'] = ((data['cts'] - data['cts'][0]) / 1000).round(2)
data

Please post sample of your data. The problem is there

I've updated my post to include how I load the data. You can now see the code that demonstrates the process of loading data from multiple CSV files into a dictionary.
